# template method specialization for ptr to struct and vector of ptr to struct?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming

If I have a variant that contain two types- pointer to struct, and vector of pointer to struct. How do I specialize the two template methods in boost::static_visitor to handle those two cases?

```
    boost::variant<a*,b*,c*,vector<a*>*, vector<b*>*, vector<c*>*>
```

Comment: What is `static_visitor`?

Comment: I mean boost::static_visitor. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/static_visitor.html

Comment: What have you tried?  The short version is "easily" but I have no idea what is blocking you. Are`a` `b` and `c` concrete classes, or are they placeholders?  What do you want the visitor to do?

Comment: Oh, and what do you want your visitor to return?  `void`?

Comment: @Yakk yes, void as return

Comment: @Yakk a, b, c are struct type. I tried template< template<class, class> class V, typename T>> for the vector template, not sure is it correct either. And I have no idea how to define the template method just for pointer to struct. I don't want to specialize every individual types from the variant, i am trying to keep this "generic"?

Answer (score 0):

Have your visitor functor inherit from `static_visitor<void>`, or just `typedef void result_type`.  Then have an override of for each type in your `variant` -- this can be via templates, or by explicit overrides.

```
struct my_visitor: static_visitor<void> {
  void operator()( a* ) const {
    std::cout << "I see an a*\n";
  }
  void operator()( b* ) const {
    std::cout << "I see a b*\n";
  }
  void operator()( c* ) const {
    std::cout << "I see a c*\n";
  }
  void operator()( std::vector<c*>* ) const {
    std::cout << "I see a std::vector<c*>*\n";
  }
  void operator()( std::vector<b*>* ) const {
    std::cout << "I see a std::vector<b*>*\n";
  }
  void operator()( std::vector<a*>* ) const {
    std::cout << "I see a std::vector<a*>*\n";
  }
};
```

As an aside, storing raw pointers in a `boost::variant` seems like a poor idea -- I'd want to store smart pointers or instances of the object.  Similar for storing pointers to `std::vector`.  There are use cases to store raw pointers, but they are not all that common.

A `boost::variant< a, b, c, std::vector<a>, std::vector<b>, std::vector<c> >`, or if your types are polymorphic interfaces, `std::shared_ptr` to same (last I checked `boost::variant` is not move-aware, so `std::unique_ptr` doesn't work well it).

Imagine if you just want to ignore the `std::vector` instances;
    struct my_visitor: static_visitor {
      void operator()( a* ) const {
        std::cout << "I see an a*\n";
      }
      void operator()( b* ) const {
        std::cout << "I see a b*\n";
      }
      void operator()( c* ) const {
        std::cout << "I see a c*\n";
      }
      template
      void operator()( std::vector* ) const {
        std::cout << "I see a std::vector*\n";
      }
    };
or, if you wanted to ignore everything that looks like a container:

```
// container traits class, detects if `std::begin` and `std::end` work on an instance of the data:
template<typename C, bool=true>
struct is_container:std::false_type {};
template<typename C>
struct is_container<C, std::is_same< std::begin(std::declval<C&>()), std::end(std::declval<C&>()) >::value>:
  std::true_type
{};


struct my_visitor: boost::static_visitor<void> {
  // blah blah blah

  // SFINAE detection of C being a container:
  template<typename C>
  typename std::enable_if< is_container<C>::value >::type operator()( C* ) const {
    std::cout << "I see a Container<?>*\n";
  }
};
```

in a C++11 compiler.

Comment: is it possible to have template method specialize for just "pointer to a struct" or as you suggest "shared_ptr to a struct"?

Comment: Sure, but what are you going to *do* with this unknown typed data if you don't have the type?  Do you just want to ignore `std::vector<T*>*` arguments, or you don't care what the type `T` is in how you handle them?